# Can't erase the first 256KB of Nor Flash(M29W256GL) using BDI2000

Tags: embedded, powerpc, u-boot

I'm porting u-boot-2013.10 to MPC8306 based board. Previously, I can erase the first several sectors of Nor Flash using BDI2000. But after sometime, when the porting task is nearly done, (I mean that I can use gdb to trace the code execution and find the u-boot code runs into command line mainloop, though there are no serial output at the time, due to error configure of Serial Port)the first 256KB of Nor Flash can't be erased even if after power off reset. Other sectors can be erased normally.

The Nor Flash is Micron M29W256GL, with block size 128KB. I'm sure the WP# Pin has been pulled high, so there is no hardware protection upon the first block.

When config the jumper on board to change the PowerPC Config Word in order not to let MPC8306 fetch boot code at power up, the problem remains.

I used to run u-boot-1.1.6 on this board, I have erased this version of u-boot so many times without the problem mentioned above. I guess u-boot-2013.10 made some new approach to flash manipulation or others, for example, non-volatile protection on first 256KB of flash.

Is there someone can help me to solve the problem? I would very much appreciate your help.